# Should we use the most or least amount of tags in a question?

Tags: discussion, tags

Tagging on questions is many times flexible - there are overlapping tags which are all relevant to the question and one can choose the least amount of tags needed or all the tags that are relevant (up to 5).

**Example 1:** (please ignore that it's a duplicate, it's an example)

A standard homework question in C where the user has trouble reading input from a file can be tagged with the following tags:

[c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) [file-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-io) [input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/input) [file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file) [stdio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdio) [fscanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fscanf) [readfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readfile)  ...

Here the help page suggests that [file-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-io) contains [file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file) and [input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/input). I believe that [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)[file-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-io) and [fscanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fscanf) are the minimum, but I can't feel comfortable removing the others if I see them.

**Example 2:**

A question where the user is having trouble performing custom painting of some shape in Java Swing (or any other GUI library):

[java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing) [user-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface)[paint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paint)[paintcomponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paintcomponent)[draw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/draw)[drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawing)[drawing2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawing2d)(<-- what is this?)[graphics2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphics2d)[custom-painting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-painting)(<-- ?)[shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shapes)[jpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpanel)(or [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas))...

Here I believe [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)[swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing)[paintcomponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paintcomponent) are the minimum, but again, the others are not wrong. The help page does suggest not to use the obscure tags I noted (should they even exist?)

**Question**

What are the guidelines for tagging? Trying to pick the minimum amount and so the most specific tags ([fscanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fscanf) and not [stdio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdio), [swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing) and not [user-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface)), or trying to make the question as specific as possible and so as many tags as possible (adding [shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shape) in the 2nd example)?

The [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) doesn't give guidance, and perhaps it should.

(If anyone wants to add more examples for other languages/technologies, feel free to edit.)

Comment: If you keep in mind what the primary purpose of tags are (to help experts on a particular topic find your question), this question seems to answer itself. Use as many tags as make sense. There is a hard limit of 5, but nothing wrong with filling all 5 spots if they apply to your question and you want experts on that topic to see your question.

Comment: At the same time there's nothing preventing you from using just one tag, *the tag*. You need to decide what kind of public you want to attract or not. Adding unrelated tags may cause your question to be left unanswered or even downvoted (the "why the heck I'm seeing this question" kind of downvote). I've had good experiences by using anything from a single tag to 5. So, bottom line is: which tags are the most appropriated to get this question seen by the people that can give closure. That's the best criteria instead of looking for a magic number.

Comment: Well, the first one will with near-certainty be low quality, or at least a common duplicate he should really have found, and quite likely a typo, regardless of how (in-)appropriately it's tagged. Not guaranteed though, or we would outright ban homework.

Comment: @Deduplicator Updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One should simply use the *right* number of tags for the question, no less no more.

---

Seriously though, there isn't a rule that will fit all situations. We have a minimum of one tag and a maximum of 5 - that should be enough for anyone, in particular given the scope we expect of questions - that they be answerable in a few paragraphs.

The rule of thumb - use tags that focus on the essence of the question, be it language, technique, platform or concept.